# Right parenthesis error in oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT titol, data_prestec 
FROM if_llibres, if_llibre_prestec
WHERE 
    if_llibre_prestec.ubicacio = if_llibres.ubicacio
    AND data_devolucio IS NULL
    AND data_prestec <= date_sub(current_date(),interval 30 day);
```

Comment: Ivan - To receive more constructive feedback, try sharing the exact error and the steps you have taken to try to resolve the issue.  Also, some more context in which the SQL query is called (e.g. database schema, what you are trying to accomplish) will help contributors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `DATE_SUB()` function in Oracle. You could phrase this as:

```
select 
    titol, 
    data_prestec 
from if_llibres il
inner join if_llibre_prestec ilp 
    on ilp.ubicacio = il.ubicacio 
where 
    data_devolucio is null 
    and data_prestec <= current_date - interval '30' day;
```

Note that I rewrote your query to use a standard, explicit join (with the `on` keyword) rather than an implicit join (with a comma in the `from` clause): this old syntax from decades ago should not be used in new code.

I would also recommend prefixing each column in the `SELECT` and `WHERE` clause with the (alias of the) table it belongs to: this makes the query unambiguous and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting 30 days *smells like* "previous month". If that was your intention, well, not all months have 30 days so you'll get wrong result. Note that Oracle offers the `ADD_MONTHS` function which allows you to subtract any number of *months*. In your case - 1 month.

Furthermore, `current_date` returns both date **and** time, so of you subtract 1 month (or 30 days, doesn't matter), you'll move back to that very *second*, not date itself.

Here's what I mean:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_Date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select current_date as curdat,
  2         current_date - interval '30' day as cur_30,
  3         add_months(current_date, -1) as adm_1,
  4         --
  5         trunc(current_date) - interval '30' day as cur_trun_30,
  6         add_months(trunc(current_date), -1) as adm_trun_1
  7  from dual;

CURDAT              CUR_30              ADM_1               CUR_TRUN_30         ADM_TRUN_1
------------------- ------------------- ------------------- ------------------- -------------------
14.06.2020 21:49:43 15.05.2020 21:49:43 14.05.2020 21:49:43 15.05.2020 00:00:00 14.05.2020 00:00:00

SQL>
```

- `CURDAT` is current date (along with time)
- `CUR_30` subtracted 30 days; as you can see, you aren't on 14.05. but 15.05. **at** 21:49:43 so your query will return rows whose date value depends on that time as well
- `ADM_1` subtracted 1 month from current date, and it brought you back to 14.05. - again with the time component
- `CUR_TRUN_30` truncated current date (and "removed" the time component, setting time to midnight at beginning of that day), but you're again at 15.05. - not 14.05.
- `ADM_TRUN_1` truncated current date and set you to 14.05.2020 00:00 which is - I believe - what you wanted

Therefore, my suggestion would be

```
SELECT titol, 
       data_prestec 
FROM if_llibres join if_llibre_prestec ON if_llibre_prestec.ubicacio = if_llibres.ubicacio
WHERE data_devolucio IS NULL
  AND data_prestec <= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(current_date), -1);
```

Not related to your problems, but I'd suggest you to *always* use table aliases. The way you wrote the query, it is impossible to know which column belongs to which table and it makes confusion.